# spring security 4.0.1 - HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC (4.1.6 RELEASE) and Spring Security (4.0.1 RELEASE).

When i am trying to submit my login form ,i am getting "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported ." Error.

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ISMServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ISMServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan  base-package="com.sam"/>

<security:http auto-config='true' >    
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403.html"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.html"   authentication-failure-url="/error.html" default-target-url="/home.html" /> 
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ism" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

form.html

```
<form  action="j_spring_security_check" name="f" method="post" >

            <input name="j_username" type="text" />
            <input name="j_password" type="password"/>
            <input name="submit" id="button" type="submit" value="enter" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Could you post your Controller Class (e.g. Mappings defined) ?

Answer (score 1):

The default login endpoint for login submit action is /login. You have in your login.html the endpoint j_spring_security_check where spring don't knows how it handle this mapping. So try it also with input elements with ids/names username/password:

```
<form  action="/login" name="f" method="post" >
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password"/>
    <input name="submit" id="button" type="submit" value="enter" />
</form>
```

Please modify both entries (servlet-config.xml, spring-security.xml) in <context:component-scan base-package="com.sam.*"/>.
Change the url-mapping to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ISMServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: i did but it gave this error HTTP Status 404 - /login

Comment: Do you have any additional logs, infos, stacktrace?

Comment: i did but it gave again this error HTTP Status 404 - /login

Comment: Please give me some more information like: url after login post (in browser), network infos from e.g. firebug (maybe a redirect to another url...), tomcat logs. Could you verify if you are logged in after sending login formular?

Comment: http://localhost:8085/ISM/login.html  - login page address  and after clicking enter in login form that is the adress http://localhost:8085/login that has the 404 error

Comment: What if you configure only with <security:form-login /> and let Spring offer the login page?

Comment: it works properly without any error but i need to use a custom login page

Comment: Has anyone resolved this issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that csrf protection is enabled by default in sprng-security 4. So add this line in your login form

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

servlet-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sam.controller"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <map>
                            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                        </map>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                        <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="language"/>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" p:defaultLocale="fa"/>

<bean id="messageSource" 
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" 
          p:basename="messages">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="2"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="0"/>
```

contoller.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goHomePage(Model model) throws IOException {
        return "home";
    }
}
```